# Call an array including into another file with php

Tags: php, include

Why this do not work and how can I solve it please ?

**Main page:**

```
$a = include 'module_a.php';
print_r($a);
```

**module_a.php page:**

```
function go() {
    include 'datas.php';
    return $array;
}
```

**datas.php page:**

```
$array = array();
$array[10] = 'bla';
$array[11] = 'blo';
return $array;
```

I do not have any error in the console except that no code is print.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have a return statement not in the function and you include it, it will only return the value where you included it.

Comment: I have missed one line in my code. Question is now updated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it should be somehow like this:

```
include 'module_a.php';
$a = go();
print_r($a);
```

To your post update: datas.php doesn't have to return `$array`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is printed because you define `function go` but you never execute it. Do:

```
include 'module_a.php';
print_r(go());
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `go` function

**index.php**

```
<?php

$a = include 'module_a.php';
print_r($a);
```

**module_a.php**

```
function go() {
    include 'datas.php';
    return $array;
}

return go();
```

**datas.php**

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array[10] = 'bla';
$array[11] = 'blo';

return $array;
```